# The probability that you sleep at least $8$ hours for $3$ or more nights in a given week

Tags: probability

17) You have been having some trouble sleeping. If there’s an $80\%$ chance that you sleep at least $8$ hours in a night, what’s the probability (to the nearest hundredth) that you will be able to get at least $8$ hours of sleep for $3$ or more nights in a given week?

**answer**

We are finding the probability of sleeping at least $8$ hours for $5$ days in a week

so the probability we are finding is: sleeping at least 8 hours in a night and probability that you sleep at least 8 hours in a night for 5 days in a week

The answer is $0.8 \cdot 5/7 =0.5714$.

I'm not sure about that answer.

Comment: In your title, you said five days in a week.  In the body, you wrote three or more days in a week.  Which did you mean?

Comment: Ignore the title. Use information in the question only

Answer (score 2):

There are  $7$ "experiments" that all have probability $0.8$ to succeed.

Preassuming that the experiments are independent (actually in the real situation I don't think so) the answer must be: $$P(X\geq3)$$ where $X$ has [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) with parameters $n=7$ and $p=0.8$.

If you are thinking of a week having $5$ days then of course $7$ must be interchanged with $5$.

I leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{7}{3} = 35$ possibilities to choose 3 out of 7 days. For each of these possibilities, you have a $0.8^3\cdot 0.2^4 = \frac{0.028672}{35}$ chance of sleeping for 8 hours or longer on any of these 3 days, while sleeping less than 8 hours on all of the other days. This means that your probability of sleeping for 8 hours or longer on $\textbf{exactly}$ 3 days equals $0.028672$. Repeat for 4, 5, 6 and 7 days and sum up the probabilities to sum up the solution (or just do so for 1 and 2 days and subtract from $1$).

Comment: The question asks us to find the probability that you get at least 8 hours of sleep for 3 or more nights in a given week, not just 3 nights like you are saying. I'm i mistaken?

Comment: @sirkal That's why you are summoned in this answer to *repeat* it for $4,5,6$ and $7$.